# Lmer model syntax for a repeated measures with multiple trials - R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

In my research, I looked into how certain treatments, given over a specific period of time, affect how quickly the subjects can perform certain tasks. For each measurement, the subjects had to complete a task as fast as possible, with two attempts allowed. Both attempts made each day were used in the final analysis.

This is the structure of my data:
id: identifier for each subject.
treatment: treatment group of the subject.
day: day of observation
trial: trial number
speed: speed measurement.

```
# A tibble: 784 × 5
    id     treatment          trial day   speed
    <chr>  <chr>              <fct> <fct> <dbl>
  1 K108_3 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     0      2660
  2 K108_3 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     1      3030
  3 K108_3 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     3      3420
  4 K108_3 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     7      7040
  5 K108_3 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     15     2210
  6 K108_3 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     0      2250
  7 K108_3 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     1      2830
  8 K108_3 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     3      3150
  9 K108_3 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     7      2800
 10 K108_3 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     15     2290
 11 K113_1 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     0      2030
 12 K113_1 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     1      7720
 13 K113_1 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     3      8670
 14 K113_1 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     7      2280
 15 K113_1 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     15     4320
 16 K113_1 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     0      1580
 17 K113_1 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     1      3380
 18 K113_1 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     3      4140
 19 K113_1 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     7      2610
 20 K113_1 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     15     2680
 21 K116_2 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     0      1970
 22 K116_2 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     1      5620
 23 K116_2 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     3      7060
 24 K116_2 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     7      3570
 25 K116_2 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 1     15     3100
 26 K116_2 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     0      2870
 27 K116_2 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     1      4200
 28 K116_2 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     3      9050
 29 K116_2 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     7      6730
 30 K116_2 Group_A_BTX_HS_sal 2     15     2990
# ℹ 754 more rows
```

I wrote this formula:

```
model <- lmer(speed ~ treatment + day + treatment * day + (1|id), my_data)
```

This is how I understand it:

Speed: is the dependent variable or response variable I want to predict.

Treatment and day: are independent variables or predictors. Each of them represents a different factor that might influence the dependent variable.

Treatment * day: This term represents an interaction between the "treatment" and "day" variables. An interaction term indicates that the effect of one variable on the dependent variable might depend on the level of another variable. In this case, it suggests that the effect of treatment on speed might be different on different days.

(1|id): is specifying a random effect. The "id" variable represents the subjects or participants in the study. This indicates that there is a random intercept for each subject. This acknowledges that there might be individual variability that is not explained by the fixed effects (like treatment or day) but is unique to each subject.

But! I'm unsure about how to fit the trial into this formula. I do know that the trial should somehow be nested in the day variable, but I'm not sure about the exact way to do it. It doesn't seem like a good idea to just average the two trials for each day and put those values into the model. While this would make the model simpler, it could also result in losing a lot of valuable information.
Also I am not sure if day variable should be character, factor or numerical.

I was thinking that the formula might look something like this, however, I'm uncertain about the correct syntax, as I mentioned earlier.

```
model <- lmer(speed ~ treatment + day + treatment * day + (1|id/trial), my_data)
```

or

```
model <- lmer(speed ~ treatment + day + trial + treatment * day + (1|id), my_data)
```

Any assistance or advice regarding literature specific to this question is welcome.